# In Excel find, cut and paste an entire row to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find, cut and paste an entire row from one Excel sheet to another sheet, then delete the blank row in the first sheet.  Additionally, if the conditional value cannot be found I need a message box.  I have two problems with the code shown below:

1. if the value is found in column A, then before the copy and paste happens, the code tries to open a new workbook which I have to hit cancel
2. If the value is not found in column A then the code creates the message box multiple times.  Any help is much appreciated.

Code is Here:

```
Sub Allocate()

    Dim UsdRws As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    UsdRws = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

    For i = UsdRws To 2 Step -1

        If Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("AMode").Range("C2") Then
            Rows(i).Copy Workbooks("allocations development").Sheets("AL").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Rows(i).Delete

        Else: MsgBox "Loan Number Not Found"

        End If

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need. Pay attention to comments I made.

```
Sub Allocate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim checkSheet As Worksheet
    Set checkSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheet") 'change to needed name

    Dim loanNumber As String
    loanNumber = Worksheets("AMode").Range("C2").Value

    If Not checkSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).Find(loanNumber, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then

        Dim usdRows As Long
        usdRows = checkSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

        Dim allocDev As Workbook
        Set allocDev = Application.Workbooks("allocations developments") 'assumes it's already open

        Dim i As Long
        For i = UsdRws To 2 Step -1

            If checkSheet.Range("A" & i).Value = loanNumber Then
                checkSheet.Rows(i).Copy allocDev.Sheets("AL").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                checkSheet.Rows(i).Delete
            End If

        Next

    Else

        MsgBox "Loan Number Not Found"

    End If

End Sub
```